# Angularjs: how do i pass a value from a form to a other form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, angular-controller

i need to get the Id from a table and pass it to a controller, i did something like that but the id value is lost every time i change the form, i would like know if there is a way to do that,i added the service code, and the controllers code

```js
//Here in get the IdValue

app.controller('SeguimientoSolicitudesController', ['$scope', 'ParametrosSolicitudes', function ($scope, ParametrosSolicitudes) {
        this.SegSolic = "";        
        var self = this;

        $scope.ValorId = function (value) {
            ParametrosSolicitudes.setVarIdSolicitud(value);
            window.location.href = urlServer + "Home/About";
        };


        solicitudContext.obtenerListaSegSolicitudes(function (resp) {
            switch (resp.ressult) {
                case "tgp":
                    self.SegSolic = solicitudContext.ListaSeguimientoSolicitudes;
                    break;
                case "notgp":
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            $scope.$apply();
        });       
    }]);
```

```js
//Here i get the detail of the id selected but the value is missing
app.controller('SolicitudesController', ['$scope', 'ParametrosSolicitudes', 'parametroConstante', function ($scope, ParametrosSolicitudes, parametroConstante) {
        this.SolicitudDetalle = "";
        var IdSolicitud = '';
        var self = this;

        $scope.$watch(function () { return ParametrosSolicitudes.getVarIdSolicitud() }, function () {
            IdSolicitud = ParametrosService.getVarIdSolicitud();
        });
        solicitudContext.obtenerListaSolicitudes('R', IdSolicitud, function (resp) {
            switch (resp.ressult) {
                case "tgp":
                    self.SolicitudDetalle = solicitudContext.ListaSolicitudes;
                    break;
                case "notgp":
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            $scope.$apply();
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: Rafa, window.location.href is reloading the page? Could you check that? If true I can teach you how to do properly. Regards (I'm a spanish native speaker)

Comment: Hola que tal, si window.location.href esta recargando la página, sería de gran ayuda si me dices como hacerlo de manera correcta.

Comment: Hola Rafa, cuando llamas a esta ruta: urlServer + "Home/About", es que se usa el controller SolicitudesController?

Comment: Así es, ese es el controller que usa

Comment: Entiendes la respuesta q te puse abajo, el lio es q estas refrescando la pagina y pierdes todo lo que este en el cliente, por ejemplo las variables. Entonces puedes hacer varias cosas o guardas la variable en un localStorage o en un coockie, pero para mi la mejor solucion es NO refrescar la pagina

Comment: Si, si entiendo la respuesta, entonces tendría que hacer todas mis solicitudes en el mismo formulario sin refrescar la página?

Comment: No se la logica completa de la app, pero si quieres compartir datos entre un contoller y otro NO puedes refrescar la pagina, igual para ayudarte bien puedes crear un fidle que sea cerca a lo que quieres?

Comment: Pues en la app lo que hago es llenar un grid y me muestra los registros que consulto, uno de esos registros es un id, con ese id tengo que hacer otra consulta para mostrar el detalle, pero ese detalle lo tengo que mostrar en otro formulario, con lo que me has dicho entiendo que tengo que usar $location.search(); pero no entiendo de que manera implementarlo

Comment: Es como una lista donde un campo(id) puedes darle click y te lleva a una vista de detalles de la entidad q tiene ese id, te voy a hacer un ejemplo fiddle, mira si quieres podemos hablar por skype, me das tu usario y te escribo

Comment: me parece mi usario es rafael.rosales.4

Comment: mira este fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9hz3d23t/5/, como no entendía bien lo q necesitas te puse 2 variantes, hay mas pero creo q te llevarás la idea. Confirmame si es lo q buscas

Comment: Gracias! No es lo que realmente buscaba pero me ayudo a solicionar otro problema que tenia, gracias por el aporte!

Comment: Me alegro, crees que si edito la respuesta que te di y pongo el ejemplo del fiddle puedas marcarla como correcta, estoy postulando a un trabajo y esto me puede ayudar, gracias

Comment: Si claro, no hay problema con eso!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rafa, you have a conceptual problem, any JS variables is going to be lost when you reload the page, this mean when you do:

window.location.href = urlServer + "Home/About"

you are lossing all data in the client side.

Then, for navigate from a page to another in AngularJS you should use: $location service, in your case something like $location.path("Home/About");

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

check this sample

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
  controller: "SeguimientoSolicitudesController",
  templateUrl: "SeguimientoSolicitudes.html" 
 })
    .when('/details/:id/', {
  controller: 'SolicitudesController', 
  templateUrl: "Solicitudes.html"
 })
}]);

app.service("shareService", function(){
 // lose this value if you reload the page, if you need it persistent you have to save to server or save to browser(cookies, localStorage)
 var name = null;
 
 return {
  getName: function(){
   return name;
  },
  setName: function(val){
   name = val;
  }
 }
})

app.controller('SeguimientoSolicitudesController', ['$scope', '$location','shareService',function ($scope, $location, shareService) {       
 $scope.list = [{id: 5, name: "NameA"}, {id: 9, name: "NameB"}];

 $scope.goToDetails = function(item){
  shareService.setName(item.name);
  $location.path("details/" + item.id);
 }
}]);    
    
app.controller('SolicitudesController', ['$scope','$routeParams','shareService',function ($scope, $routeParams, shareService) {                    
 $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
 $scope.name = shareService.getName();
}]);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container"  ng-app="app">
 <ng-view></ng-view>
  
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="SeguimientoSolicitudes.html">
    <p ng-repeat="item in list">
      <a class="btn btn-link" ng-click="goToDetails(item)" style="cursor: pointer;">{{item.name}}</a>
    </p>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="Solicitudes.html">
     <p>ID: {{id}}, NAME: {{name}}</p>
      <a class="btn btn-link" href="#/">back</a>
  </script>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Hope I help you